# What is wrong with this statements?

Tags: java, logging

I have been told by one of my senior that write log statements for two levels , `debug` and `info` is wrong , what is wrong with this approach ?

```
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()){
    LOGGER.info("REST SERVICE LOG :QUERY GENERATED FOR ADVANCED SEARCH IS : \n" +queryBuffer );
}
if(LOGGER.isEnabledFor(Level.INFO)){
    LOGGER.info("REST SERVICE LOG :QUERY GENERATED FOR ADVANCED SEARCH IS : \n" +queryBuffer );
}
```

Any suggestions on this please ?

Comment: Was your "senior" unwilling to explain the reason?

Comment: He said why to write same log statements for different levels  when just writing log statements for debug level is enough .

Comment: So why do you feel the need to ask here? Do you not believe him? Was he unwilling to explain it sufficiently for you to not have questions?

Comment: @DevG Do you mean that he said that writing them for the **info** level is enough? Info implies debug but not the other way around.

Comment: Your code does ***not*** "write log entries for TWO levels".

Comment: @ErwinSmout  Yes exactly  , but what is wrong with writing two statements , if log level is info then second statement gets executed and if it is Debug then first statements gets executed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example: (Assuming your LOGGER is using one of the standard java logging frameworks)

If LOGGER is configured for TRACE or DEBUG, then the same information will be logged twice.

```
"REST SERVICE LOG :QUERY GENERATED FOR ADVANCED SEARCH IS : 
<query buffer>"
"REST SERVICE LOG :QUERY GENERATED FOR ADVANCED SEARCH IS : 
<query buffer>"
```

That seems wasteful.

If LOGGER is configured for INFO, then the information will be logged once.

```
"REST SERVICE LOG :QUERY GENERATED FOR ADVANCED SEARCH IS : 
<query buffer>"
```

If LOGGER is configured for a level like ERROR or FATAL, then no information will be logged.

What is your goal for logging here?

Comment: So we don't have to write log statements for both info and debug if log level is set as debug ?

Comment: Well...yes, but the writer of the code doesn't control the log level setting, so when writing the code the developer must write the logging statements based on what he or she wants to be logged.